# What's the best approach for a red light so you'll pass at maximum speed when it turns green?

Tags: probability, optimization

So me and a couple of friends were driving back home when we started wondering about this (admittedly silly) question. Say you are driving your car on a straight lane and see a red light up ahead. What is the best course of action to do, so that when it turns green you'll pass it at maximum speed possible?

For sake of simplicity, we're putting aside more complicated situations like if the road is curved or uphill or there are other cars or whatever. All you have is a pretty decent assumption of the length between you and the traffic light, and knowing that the red light will change between, say, the next 1 and 45 seconds.

To clarify, we obviously understand there's no fullproof solution that will always work, because we don't know the exact timing until the light turns green. Instead we're looking for a constant mathematical method that will work most of the time (i.e., where the percentage of success is the highest possible), and that will also not break any laws (we can't apply a method where we speed up and hope it changes, we have to account for the possibility of having to stop if it doesn't on time).

Also, assume we're only interested in saving time (ignore gas usage and other issues). Thank you all

Comment: You would have to know how the stoplight algorithm works I assume

Comment: This is something I've thought about too.  I convinced myself that if you know the exact time of the change, the best you can do is to immediately slow to such a speed that lets you arrive at the light just as it turns green.  I'll be interested to see how this strategy changes given a probabilistic distribution of "green times".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that's what my good friend thought too. I was thinking it's better to gradually slow down so you can avoid stopping completely, but none of us could think of a mathematical solution to prove either

Comment: Actually, after looking at @RobertIsrael's answer, I think his strategy is better if your only concern is to be going through the stop light at the maximum possible speed.  If, on the other hand, your concern is to slow down as little as possible (for example, if you're "hypermiling" and want to lose as little of your kinetic energy as possible), then the immediate braking strategy is better.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this could be solved analytically in any straightforward way but would be easy peasy in Matlab.

Comment: I came here to ask this question. @RobertIsrael's answer maximizes the speed through the intersection but obviously isn't what you meant to ask.. I think another way to put it is that you want to maximize your speed at the moment the light turns green and minimize the distance you are from the intersection. Robert's answer is the worst possible solution in that regard.

Comment: My intuition is that you maximize your speed when the light turns green and minimize your distance to the light with this strategy: As soon as you notice the red light, slow down at a constant rate such that you'd reach 0 perfect at the intersection. Keep doing this while its red. As soon as it is green, you can 'floor it' until you hit your maximum speed (if any). The success of this is highly dependent on the time-to-green. But expressing this mathematically isn't my forte.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395125.

Answer (score 1):

There is some point $p$ such that, from a standing start at $p$ with maximum acceleration, you would reach the speed limit when you pass the light. Stop at $p$ (if the light hasn't already turned green when you get there) and wait for the light to turn green.  Then floor it.

Comment: I suspect that the OP didn't mean to ask a question to which this is the answer, but I'm compelled to +1 any answer that ends with "floor it".

Comment: Question is how do you get the best possible `p` assuming you only have a range of times and not exact details

Comment: @yuvi time is uncertain, we can suppose we know the distances (and p, too). Anyhow I also was hoping for a more mathematical explanation :P

Comment: I agree with @pjs36: this does answer the question that was asked, but I don't think it answers the question the OP intended to ask, which I gather is more about minimizing trip time than maximizing speed through a given intersection. After all, what would be the practical application of the latter?

Comment: I think the intended goal is to maximize your speed at the moment the light turns green, and this answer is the worst possible solution in that regard. Posted my thoughts on a better way to express the question in a comment on the question.