# Optimal speed for approaching red light to maximize velocity with non-uniform probability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, optimization, optimal-control, holder-inequality

### Problem statement

When I cross red lights, my goal is to being going as fast as possible when the light turns green.

I am at distance $D$ from a traffic light when it turns red.

Let the time length of the red light be $t_{red}$ with probability density $ p$ on $[0,T_{max}]$.

My velocity $v(t)$ must be such that $\int_{0}^{T_{max}} v(t)dt \leq D$. ( I can't cross the light while it's red.)

Given any $C$, I would like to find $v$ to maximize $E(v(t_{red}))$ given $Var(v(t_{red})) < C$.

### My best solution so far

What follows is my best family of solutions so far. I can show that it is optimal for $C=0$ and $C=\infty$ I would appreciate your help confirming or denying it is optimal for other values of $C$.

Let $F(a) = \int_0^{T_{max}}p^a(t)dt$

Note that $F(0)=T_{max}$ and $F(1)=1$

Let $v_a(t) = \frac{D}{F(a)}{p^a(t)}$.

We have

$\int_0^{T_{max}}v_a(t)dt=D$

$E(v_a(t_{red}))=\frac{D}{F(a)}\int_0^{T_{max}}p^{a}pdt=D\frac{F(a+1)}{F(a)}$

$E(v_a(t_{red})^2) =\frac{D^2}{F(a)^2}\int_0^{T_{max}}(p^a)^2pdt= D^2\frac{F(2a+1)}{F(a)^2} $

$Var(v_a(t_{red}))= D^2\frac{F(2a+1)-F(a+1)^2}{F(a)^2}$

To get a feel for the expected value and variance of this solution, I plotted it out for a simple example:

[image]

---

I can show you that this is optimal for at least two values of $a$.

### $a=0$

if $a=0$ then $E(v_0(t_{red})) = D\frac{F(1)}{F(0)}=\frac{D}{T_{max}}$.

Also $Var(v_0(t_{red})) = D\frac{F(1)-F(1)}{F(0)}=0$.

This is optimal for $C=0$ since if $C=0$ then $v$ is constant, and must satisfy $\int_{0}^{T_{max}} v(t)dt \leq D$ while trying to maximize $E(v)$.

Side note: This is also the solution of the problem if you assumed uniform probability distribution from the get-go (which for practical purposes is a fair assumption).

### $a=\infty$

I can also show that this is optimal for $a=\infty$ in this case $C=\infty$ and

this case this is simply the [extremal Holder's equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Extremal_equality)

Holder's inequality says:

$D||p||_{\infty}=sup(\int_0^{T_{max}} vpdt: ||v||_1=D)$

and since $v_{\infty}$ essentially approaches a delta function around the supremum with weight $D$ we hit this upper bound at $v_{\infty}$

Side note: this solution is hilariously nonphysical. The driver waits for the moment where the light is most likely to turn and accelerates to an astronomic velocity towards the light for a split second and the halts to a dead stop. Thats what happens when we allow infinite variance.

### Question

Of course I have just proved the two easiest cases. I would love to show that for any given $C$ the $v_a: Var(v_a) = C$ will maximize $E(v)$ for all $Var(v)\leq C$

### What I've tried

One method I have been able to think of for proving optimality is to show
if

$g: E(g(t))=0, \int_0^{T_{max}}g = 0$

then

$E(v_a^2) \leq E((v_a+g)^2) \implies Var(v_a)\leq Var(v_a+g)$.

not much came out of this approach for me.

#### One promising approach

considering instead something like $E(v_ag) \geq E(v_a)$ and $ \int_0^{T_{max}}v_ag = \int_0^{T_{max}}v_a$ the problem turns into the following:

if $  \int_0^{T_{max}}p^ag = \int_0^{T_{max}}p^a$ and  $  \int_0^{T_{max}}p^{a+1}g \geq \int_0^{T_{max}}p^{a+1}$

then does

$  \int_0^{T_{max}}p^{2a+1}g^2 \geq \int_0^{T_{max}}p^{2a+1}$ ?

this is nice as:
$p^{a}gp^{a+1}g= p^{2a+1}g^2$ and $p^{a}p^{a+2}= p^{2a+1}$.

So we almost want a rule like

$\int a \geq \int b, \int c = \int d \implies \int ac \geq \int cd$ under our assumptions.

Comment: I think you end up needing a penalty for extreme deceleration for this to be well-posed.

Comment: I think that comes from minimizing the variance. As in, as C gets smaller the solutions will look more physical.

Comment: Wait, is it a control problem where you get input from the light as you move or is it a matter of defining your intended trajectory up front?

Comment: v(t) is only while the light is red. When the light turns green the problem is over and your are judged based on your speed at that moment.

Comment: OK, so if you get there before the light turns can you stop instantly (thus having a high score some of the time and a low score some of the time, presumably)?

Comment: Exactly. If you get to the light early and it doesn't turn you will be caught with velocity zero by the end of the game.

Comment: Never mind my deleted comment; I understand now that the requirement is on the variance of the final speed, not on the variance of the light time. For the light time you know everything about the distribution $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a solution using variational calculus (though there isn’t really any calculus involved, since nothing depends on the derivative of $v$). As far as I can tell you don’t require $v$ to be non-negative, and indeed the solutions are sometimes negative.

We can initially replace the inequalities involving $D$ and $C$ by equations; once we have the solution for given $D$ and $C$, we can then maximize with respect to $D$ and $C$ subject to the inequalities.

Trying to directly formulate this as a variational problem with constraints runs into the problem that the variance isn’t linear and contains a square of an integral. We can get around this by considering the dual problem of minimizing the variance given $\mathsf E[t_{\text{red}}]$.

So assume $D$ and $E=\mathsf E[t_{\text{red}}]$ are given. Then we want to minimize

$$
\int v^2p\,\mathrm dt
$$

subject to

$$
\int v\,\mathrm dt=D
$$

and

$$
\int vp\,\mathrm dt=E\;.
$$

Introducing Lagrange multipliers for the constraints and varying

$$
\int\left(v^2p-2\lambda vp-2\mu v\right)\mathrm dt
$$

yields

$$
2vp-2\lambda p-2\mu=0
$$

and thus

$$
v=\lambda+\frac\mu p\;.
$$

Substituting into the constraints yields

$$
\int\left(\lambda+\frac\mu p\right)\mathrm dt=D\;,\\
\int\left(\lambda+\frac\mu p\right)p\,\mathrm dt=E
$$

and thus

$$
\lambda T_{\text{max}}+\mu I=D\;,\\
\lambda+\mu T_{\text{max}}=E\;,
$$

with

$$
I=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}p\;.
$$

The Lagrange multipliers can be determined from this linear system of equations and substituted into the solution.

We recover your solution for $a=0$ and $C=0$ in the case $\mu=0$, with $v=\lambda=E=\frac D{T_{\text{max}}}$.

We don’t recover your solution for $a=\infty$ and $C=\infty$, I think because you implicitly used $v\ge0$ in deriving it.

But if $p$ is positive everywhere, there should be a neighbourhood of solutions around the solution for $C=0$ that have $v$ positive everywhere, and it doesn’t have the form you were hoping for, so I’m afraid this may be somewhat disappointing (unless I made a mistake...).

Comment: This is incredible. I am excited to read through this more closely (where I will probably end up accepting it, just want to make sure I understand it first). But I am curious if more form comes up if v>0 is added as a constraint.

Comment: Thank you for this joriki. I would greatly appreciate a reference for learning more about these types of techniques.

Comment: @jrudd: You're welcome. It's been a few decades since I learned variational calculus, partly in German, so I'm afraid I don't know any current references in English besides the obvious one, Wikipedia, which is where I usually learn such things from these days. You could start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier.

Comment: Note, though, that this doesn't really use variational calculus in a deeper way: Since the derivative of $v$ doesn't occur in the functional, we're really just dealing with a continuum of independent variables – the solution would be exactly analogous in the discretized problem, where you have $n$ points in time $t_i$ at which the light will turn green with probability $p_i$, with $\sum_ip_i=1$, and you want to maximize $E=\sum_iv_ip_i$ subject to $\sum_iv_i=D$ and $\sum_iv_i^2p_i-\left(\sum_iv_ip_i\right)^2=C$.

Comment: @jrudd: I suspect that if you impose $v\ge0$, the solution will be $0$ on some intervals with low probability, and you have to introduce variables for the ends of those intervals and maximize with respect to them; your solution for $a=\infty$ and $C=\infty$ would then presumably be recovered as these intervals contract onto the points with maximal $p$ as $C\to\infty$.